# Increasing a numeric column, how do not trigger unique constraints?

Tags: mysql, sql

for example:

```
CREATE TABLE test_serial_no_entity (
  id BIGINT,
  serial_no BIGINT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO test_serial_no_entity (id, serial_no) VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO test_serial_no_entity (id, serial_no) VALUES (2,2);
INSERT INTO test_serial_no_entity (id, serial_no) VALUES (3,3);
INSERT INTO test_serial_no_entity (id, serial_no) VALUES (4,4);
```

serial_no is a unique column, when i execute the sql: `update test_serial_no_entity set serial_no=serial_no+1 where id>=1` ,
I got the error `Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '2' for key 'serial_no'  0.034 sec` in mysql, Is there any other way to solve this problem except to cancel the unique constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, update the higher values first.

```
update test_serial_no_entity 
set serial_no=serial_no+1 
where id>=1
ORDER BY serial_no DESC
```

An example of this can also be found in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html).

Comment: `update test_serial_no_entity set serial_no=serial_no+1 where id>=1 order by serial_no desc` works well

Answer (score -1):

Try loop to update one record at a time. Start from the maximum number.

```
CREATE TABLE test_serial_no_entity (
  id BIGINT,
  serial_no BIGINT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO test_serial_no_entity (id, serial_no) VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO test_serial_no_entity (id, serial_no) VALUES (2,2);
INSERT INTO test_serial_no_entity (id, serial_no) VALUES (3,3);
INSERT INTO test_serial_no_entity (id, serial_no) VALUES (4,4);

Declare @Min int, @Iterator int

Select @Min = min(serial_no) from test_serial_no_entity
Select @Iterator = max(serial_no) from test_serial_no_entity
While(@Iterator >= @Min)
BEGIN
Update test_serial_no_entity
Set serial_no = serial_no + 1
Where serial_no = @Iterator

@Iterator = @Iterator - 1
END
```